# Twitter geo/search

Tags: twitter, geocoding

I am checking Twitter Geo-search by implementing various samples by coping the same methods from this link http://thoughtfaucet.com/search-twitter-by-location/examples/.

My goal is to taking geo-search content into RSS format. I already have twitter rss search application, and now just need to put valid contents.

However, when I put something like this (geocode:41.878114, -87.629798,50mi) into Twitter search query, there is no result. The location is in Chicago, IL, and I believe it should have some tweets.

Does anyone use this practice to find surrounding tweets?, or please help and let me know if I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example you included has a space which should be removed.

```
geocode:41.878114, -87.629798,50mi
vs
geocode:41.878114,-87.629798,50mi
```